# Sync two nested mat tree expand left tree if right tree is expanded

Tags: arrays, angular-material, angular-material2

I have two arrays fromProducts and toProducts both are nested array of obj. I need to expand left tree node if right tree node with same id is expanded.update checkbox if right checkbox is checked.

[ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYLP.png)
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVC89.png)

Comment: Please read - How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)